# Error al recorrer un array multidimesional dentro de una session de php

Tags: php, session

como estan? tengo una duda, hice una session, para que contenga un array para luego utilizarlo cuando quiera en varias partes de mi pagina. la cuestion, es que al querer traer los datos de cada array dentro de esta session, me arroja errores... con el varDump() no hay drama, el tema es que debo devolver esos datos uno por uno a un jscript.

```
function CargarEnCarro($id){

session_start();
$vuelta = "hola";
$producto[]=[$id, $vuelta];
$_SESSION['CarroCompra'][]= $producto;
//var_dump($_SESSION['CarroCompra']);




 for ($i=0; $i <count($_SESSION['CarroCompra']) ; $i++) { 

     for ($j=0; $j < count($_SESSION['CarroCompra'][$i]) ; $j++) { 
         $valor=$_SESSION['CarroCompra'][$i][$j];
         echo $valor;
     }

}


}
```

El tema es que quiero probarlo mostrandolo en consola, y me da el siguiente error, justo  en la linea del echo:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in 
........ on line <b>494</b><br />
Array<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estás haciendo un lío al guardar los valores en tu variable de `$_SESSION`, la cual funciona como un array.

Por ejemplo, puedes guardar la información con una clave que la identifique. Al parecer lo que quieres es guardar dentro de `$_SESSION` otro(s) array(s) con dos elementos.

Una solución más limpia y organizada sería:

- Declarar `$producto` como un array
- Dentro de ese array guardar dos elementos, uno será identificado por la clave `id` y el otro será identificado por la clave `texto`:
- Luego agregas ese array (`$producto`) a tu variable de sesión. Puedes agregar tantos arrays como necesites...
- Luego lees con un simple `foreach` el contenido de la variable de sesión, buscando cada elemento por su clave.
- Si las claves fueran dispares, pero el array guarda la misma estructura, puedes leer la información con un `foreach` anidado, como se explica en el apartado **Caso particular** más abajo.

Según lo explicado, el código quedaría así:

```
$producto=array();
$vuelta = "hola";
$id=1;

$producto['id']=$id;
$producto['texto']=$vuelta;
$_SESSION['CarroCompra'][]= $producto;


foreach ($_SESSION['CarroCompra'] as $row)
{
    echo "id: {$row['id']} - texto: {$row['texto']}".PHP_EOL;
}
```

La salida por pantalla es la siguiente:

```
id: 1 - texto: hola
```

---

#### Caso particular:

Si el array por algún motivo debiera tener claves distintas, por ejemplo, imaginemos que se llena así:

```
$producto=array();
$vuelta = "hola";
$id=1;

$producto['id']=$id;
$producto['texto']=$vuelta;

$vendedor=array();
$vendedor['codigo']="Z-001";
$vendedor['nombre']="Zaqueo";
    
$_SESSION['CarroCompra'][]= $producto;
$_SESSION['CarroCompra'][]= $vendedor;
```

Puedes hacer la lectura de este modo:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['CarroCompra'] as $subarray)
{
    if (is_array($subarray))
    {
        foreach ($subarray as $k=>$v)
        {
            echo "$k:  $v ".PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;   
    }
}
```

En este caso la salida será parecida a esto:

```
id:  1 
texto:  hola 

codigo:  Z-001 
nombre:  Zaqueo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! LA verdad que si, me estaba haciendo un lío de verdad, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya sito útil @GALS. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debes poner echo $valor[0] para obtener el $id y echo $valor[1] para obtener $vuelta

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione así, no se si es lo correcto, pero funciona... vamos a ver como me va:

```
  for ($i=0; $i <count($_SESSION['CarroCompra']) ; $i++) { 

      for ($j=0; $j <count($_SESSION['CarroCompra'][$i]) ; $j++) { 

          for ($k=0; $k < count($_SESSION['CarroCompra'][$i][$j]); $k++) { 
            echo ($_SESSION['CarroCompra'][$i][$j][$k]) . ' ';
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: por favor explica como este código te solucionó el problema

Comment: Hola @Alfredo Paz, creo que es porque recorre el dato, que tiene el array,  que está dentro de la session,  cuando le hice vardump a la session, me mostraba que los productos estaban guardados dentro de un array con indice cero... asique el primer for puede estar o no, solo poniendo $session[carroDeCompra][0] ya estaría... o quizás sólo fue suerte. Ja